# Dynamically adding image in signature field in pdf using itext

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need a sample code or reference of placing signature image in a signature field by reading signature field name dynamically using itextsharp. Image should be placed above the signature field with corresponding size of signature field.. can anybody help me ..

I am trying to place a signature image in an signature field but image is not placing in an signature field. width and height of the signature field rectangle differs and if change the scale to fit, image size get differs. Here my code:

```
PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFiel‌​ds fields = stamper.AcroFields;
IList<iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.FieldPosition> signatureArea = fields.GetFieldPositions("DoctorSign");
TextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = signatureArea.First().position;
image.ScaleAbsolute(rect.Width, rect.Height);
image.SetAbsolutePosition(rect.Left -image.ScaledWidth +(rect.Width -image.ScaledWidth )/2, rect.Bottom+ (rect.Height-image.ScaledHeight)/2 );
pdfContentByte.AddImage(image)
```

Comment: Hi Noctis..thanks for your immediate response. i am trying to place a signature image in an signature field but image is not placing in an signature field. width and height of the signature field rectangle differs and if change the scale to fit, image size get differs here my code

Comment: PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;IList<iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.FieldPosition> signatureArea = fields.GetFieldPositions("DoctorSign");TextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = signatureArea.First().position;image.ScaleAbsolute(rect.Width, rect.Height); image.SetAbsolutePosition(rect.Left -image.ScaledWidth +(rect.Width -image.ScaledWidth )/2, rect.Bottom+ (rect.Height-image.ScaledHeight)/2 );pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);

Comment: @raj generally you should add new information to the question itself. You may add a comment answering a request for those information with a pointer to those additions. I did that for you here. That being said, why do you change the page content and not the signature field appearance?

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to add image by using PDFContentbyte.

Foll is an example of code in VB .NET, you may use [converter.telerik.com](http://converter.telerik.com) to convert it to c#.

```
    Imports iTextSharp.text
    Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

    ' Set the File Details
    Dim fs As New FileStream("FILE_NAME", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim reader As New PdfReader(inPDF)
    Dim document As New iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4)

    ' open writer
    Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs)
    document.Open()
    Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent


    ' create the new page and add it to the pdf
    Dim page As PdfImportedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1)
    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0)

    'Add Image
    Dim hdImg As iTextSharp.text.Image
    hdImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Images\sample.png")
    Dim wid As Integer = page.Width
    hdImg.ScalePercent(50)

    hdImg.SetAbsolutePosition(30, 775)
    cb.AddImage(hdImg)

    ' close the streams
    document.Close()
    fs.Close()
    writer.Close()
    reader.Close()
```

Also, Do note that you need to do bit testing for various combinations on coordinates of the image in "SetAbsolutePosition(30, 775)" to set the signature in correct position.

Also note that the here co-ordinates are in points and not pixels. I have added wid variable so that you know what is the width of the pdf page

Comment: @ Aarn. Thanks for your code and immediate response. first of all i need to find the signature field size and then i need to set the image size same as signature field size. I can get the signature field size but i can re-size image as signature field size but i cant unable to place image over signature field. l help with that code

Comment: @raj you are using stamper & I personally faced many problems using stamper. Why not try this method
Also I have added reader, since you are adding signature in existing code..

Comment: @aarn raj has a question which is related to a signature form field. You give some code which drops all form fields and, therefore, obviously is of **no use in this context**.

Comment: @ aarn i got the answer. in set absolute position i changed the rect.left as rect.right. I got it. Thanks u both for responsing. image.SetAbsolutePosition(rect.Right -image.ScaledWidth +(rect.Width -image.ScaledWidth )/2, rect.Bottom + (rect.Height-image.ScaledHeight)/2 );

Comment: glad you got the answer. @mkl There was no mention of forms, So I thought he wanted to insert only the image.